# Combining 6 IF formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've written 6 different IF formulas, each will identify a freight carrier based on the tracking number found in cell BM71.

For the life of me I cannot figure out how to combine these, any help would be appreciated.

```
=IF(AND(LEN(BM71)=18,LEFT(BM71,2)="1Z"), "UPS", "")
=IF(AND(LEN(BM71)=12,ISNUMBER(BM71)),"FedEx","")
=IF(AND(LEN(BM71)=10,ISNUMBER(BM71)),"DHL","")
=IF(AND(LEN(BM71)=11,LEFT(BM71,2)="06"), "Old Dominion", "")
=IF(AND(LEN(BM71)=9,LEFT(BM71,2)="00"), "Arcbest", "")
=IF(AND(LEN(BM71)=10,LEFT(BM71,2)="00"), "Averitt", "")
```

Comment: Instead of so many if(), I would use a lookup table.

Comment: Even I would use a lookup table as mentioned above by @SolarMike Sir. It will be easy one.

Comment: yes, lookup table is indeed the best way to handle many conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just add a new IF in the False part. Like this:

```
=IF(AND(LEN(BM71)=18,LEFT(BM71,2)="1Z"), "UPS",
IF(AND(LEN(BM71)=12,ISNUMBER(BM71)),"FedEx",
IF(AND(LEN(BM71)=10,ISNUMBER(BM71)),"DHL",
IF(AND(LEN(BM71)=11,LEFT(BM71,2)="06"), "Old Dominion",
IF(AND(LEN(BM71)=9,LEFT(BM71,2)="00"), "Arcbest",
IF(AND(LEN(BM71)=10,LEFT(BM71,2)="00"), "Averitt", ""))))))
```

Answer (score 4):

With ifS function it gets more clean:

```
 =IFs(AND(LEN(BM71)=18,LEFT(BM71,2)="1Z"), "UPS", 
    AND(LEN(BM71)=12,ISNUMBER(BM71)),"FedEx",
    AND(LEN(BM71)=10,ISNUMBER(BM71)),"DHL",
    AND(LEN(BM71)=11,LEFT(BM71,2)="06"), "Old Dominion",
    AND(LEN(BM71)=9,LEFT(BM71,2)="00"), "Arcbest",
    AND(LEN(BM71)=10,LEFT(BM71,2)="00"), "Averitt",
True,"")
```

Comment: upvote for this one. `IFS` has been around for a while now and it is a shame not using it. Just 1 note: to have an 'else' case in `IFS` and avoid it return `#N/A!`, you need to append 1 last case with true: `IFS(<all the other cases>, TRUE, "")`. It is well explained in the [remarks of the function documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/ifs-function-36329a26-37b2-467c-972b-4a39bd951d45#ID0EDH).

Comment: IFS was my initial approach, but I couldn't figure that out so i nested some IF statements.

Comment: @WeAreOne you can use `SWITCH()` as well, it has a default param where you can use `""` for the `#N/A!`

Answer (score 2):

No love for `LET`?

Something like:

```
=LET(x,BM71,l,LEN(x),b,ISNUMBER(x),s,LEFT(x,2),IFS(
(l=18)*(s="1Z"),"UPS",
(l=12)*b,"FedEx",
(l=10)*b,"DHL",
(l=11)*(s="06"),"Old Dominion",
(l=9)*(s="00"),"Arcbest",
(l=10)*(s="00"),"Averitt"))
```

If nothing else it cuts down the formula length, and the function only takes one input cell reference (rather than 12 ...).

EDIT: Though if it were me (as other comments have mentioned) I would use this:

```
=LET(x,BM71,l,LEN(x),b,ISNUMBER(x),s,LEFT(x,2),c,IFS(
(l=18)*(s="1Z"),1,
(l=12)*b,2,
(l=10)*b,3,
(l=11)*(s="06"),4,
(l=9)*(s="00"),5,
(l=10)*(s="00"),6,
TRUE,7),INDEX(Carriers,c) )
```

With the range named `Carriers` holding the list of carriers, with a blank in the last row. Makes it easier to change a carrier name and you keep the list in one place which can be re-used by other formulas. (But then I am a devotee of the `Third Normal Form` ...)

Comment: You also could add a final ,true,"" like Atmo wrote in his comment. I have problems with LET because it seems one can not evaluate parts of the formula with F9. That is a big disadvantage. How do you handle this?

Comment: @WeAreOne The main power of LET is that you do a calculation once and store the answer (as you would in a program): in the other solutions LEN(BM71) is called six times (not to mention the number of characters this takes up in the formula). If you wanted to change the input cell in the non-LET solutions, you would have to do it in 12 places: with LET only one. Above all, LET is a great space-saver, and really shines when you start dealing with dynamic array inputs.

Answer (score 1):

You can add next one instead of "" of previous formula

```
=IF(AND(LEN(BM71)=18,LEFT(BM71,2)="1Z"), "UPS", IF(AND(LEN(BM71)=12,ISNUMBER(BM71)),"FedEx",IF(AND(LEN(BM71)=10,ISNUMBER(BM71)),"DHL",IF(AND(LEN(BM71)=11,LEFT(BM71,2)="06"), "Old Dominion", IF(AND(LEN(BM71)=9,LEFT(BM71,2)="00"), "Arcbest", IF(AND(LEN(BM71)=10,LEFT(BM71,2)="00"), "Averitt", ""))))))
```

However you approach to define something based on length and some chars is not stable
I hope I could help you